database not connected in Oracle Forms Builder
I am using a virtual box v7.
When open Oracle 9i Forms Builder and when click on connect, I have the following error even though I fill the User Name, Password and Database.
I can't show the screenshot for the error but it says ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error when not filled.When filled, for example User Name:ADMIN, Password:admin and Database:ADMIN it says:ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve service name.
Any help,
regards,
Fabrice
I expect the connection to be success when press on ok and no error. I have created some database in sql developer and used the same User Name, Password and Database names filled but no success.Its says still the error mentioned above.
For example I used ADMIN as Username and Password:admin. Normailly it was working before and now also for sql developer.
Any help.
Thanks.
